# Conditional filtering not working in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app in R that will: i) use two radiobuttons to filter a data set, ii) plot the filtered data set, and iii) use brushpoints to identify outlier points for futher inspection.

Below is a short version of my data set as well as the shiny code. The filtering based on the first radiobutton appears to be working correctly. However, the wheels come off the bus with the filtering based on the second radiobuttion. I am trying to setup the code so that values `>=` the value of the second radiobutton are plotted, but this is not happening and I have not figured out what the problem is.

Here is where I think the problem is...but I am at a loss at this point.

```
plot_subset_df <- reactive({
    filter(sub_react$data, CODE == input$CODE & DAYS_DIFFERENCE <= input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE)})
```

While much of this code is written in `dplyr` and `DT`, I trying to move to base package...so all solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Example data set

```
sub <- read.table(text = "NUMBER DEPTH DAYS_DIFFERENCE CODE DAY MONTH YEAR INHA
1   0.81    0   BROA    16  8   1986    64.35
2   NA  NA  BROA    16  8   1986    64.35
1   0.67    7   BROA    4   9   1987    60.48
2   NA  NA  BROA    4   9   1987    60.48
1   0.67    14  BROA    29  9   1987    58.68
2   1   14  BROA    29  9   1987    58.68
1   0.96    20  BROA    21  8   1988    36.72
2   NA  NA  BROA    21  8   1988    36.72
1   0.96    0   BROA    15  9   1988    38.43
2   NA  NA  BROA    15  9   1988    38.43
1   0.76    10  BROA    24  10  1988    57.69
2   NA  NA  BROA    24  10  1988    57.69
1   0.76    3   BROA    9   11  1988    41.49
2   NA  NA  BROA    9   11  1988    41.49
1   1   14  DULB    18  8   1986    64.35
2   NA  NA  DULB    18  8   1986    64.35
1   0.5 30  DULB    20  7   1987    60.48
2   NA  NA  DULB    20  7   1987    60.48
1   0.7 10  DULB    8   10  1987    58.68
2   NA  NA  DULB    8   10  1987    58.68
1   2   3   DULB    24  10  1987    36.72
2   NA  NA  DULB    24  10  1987    36.72
1   3   0   DULB    9   11  1987    38.43
2   3.5 0   DULB    9   11  1987    38.43
1   1.5 7   DULB    25  11  1987    57.69
2   NA  NA  DULB    25  11  1987    57.69
1   0.6 20  DULB    11  12  1987    41.49
2   1.2 20  DULB    11  12  1987    41.49
1   3.3 25  DULB    27  12  1987    64.35
2   2.3 25  DULB    27  12  1987    64.35
1   4.2 40  DULB    13  2   1988    60.48
2   NA  NA  DULB    13  2   1988    60.48
1   1   50  DULB    29  2   1988    58.68
2   NA  NA  DULB    29  2   1988    58.68
", header = TRUE)
```

Current version of code

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# Setup data set
sub$NUMBER = as.factor(sub$NUMBER)

# Shiny code
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
  
    radioButtons("CODE", "SWMMP code",
                 choices = unique(sub$CODE)),
    radioButtons("DAYS_DIFFERENCE", "Days difference",
                 choices = c("0" = 0,
                             "3" = 3,
                             "7" = 7,
                             "10" = 10,
                             "14" = 14,
                             "20" = 20,
                             "25" = 25,
                             "30" = 30,
                             "All" = 100000))
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush"),
    DTOutput("dt_of_brushed_points"),
    verbatimTextOutput("actual_data_brushed"),
    verbatimTextOutput("actual_data_full")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Make data set reactive values
  sub_react = reactiveValues(data = sub)
  
  # Get data for plot
  plot_subset_df <- reactive({
    filter(sub_react$data, CODE == input$CODE & DAYS_DIFFERENCE <= input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE)
  })
  
  # Make plot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(plot_subset_df(), aes(x = DEPTH, y = INHA)) + 
      geom_point(aes(size = 5, color = NUMBER))+
      theme(legend.position = "top",
            legend.title = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
  })
  
  # Display rows of data highlighted in plot
  brushed_df <- reactive({
    brushedPoints(plot_subset_df(), input$plot_brush, xvar = "DEPTH", yvar = "INHA", 
                  allRows = FALSE)})
  
  # Render highlighted data in plot
  output$dt_of_brushed_points = renderDT(brushed_df(), selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
  
  # Show actual data frame to check edits are correct
  output$actual_data_brushed <- renderPrint({brushed_df()})
  #output$actual_data_full <- renderPrint({sub_react$data})
  
  # Transfer edits from top table to bottom table
  proxy = dataTableProxy('dt_of_brushed_points')
  
  observeEvent(input$dt_of_brushed_points_cell_edit, {
    info = input$dt_of_brushed_points_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    row_to_change <-  brushed_df()[i, 1]
    sub_react$data[row_to_change, j] <- isolate(coerceValue(v, sub_react$data[row_to_change, j]))
    replaceData(proxy, sub_react$data, resetPaging = FALSE)})  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE` is of type character.  For example, if you compare "7" with values 1:20 only 8 and 9 are shown greater than 7.

```
which(1:20 > "7")
#[1] 8 9
```

change `input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE` to numeric/integer before filtering the data.

```
plot_subset_df <- reactive({
    filter(sub_react$data, CODE == input$CODE & 
           DAYS_DIFFERENCE >= as.numeric(input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE))
  })
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah! I did not notice the input produced a character. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like the problem could be the `NA`s in your `DAYS_DIFFERENCE` column. You may consider to use:

```
plot_subset_df <- reactive({
  filter(sub_react$data, CODE == input$CODE & DAYS_DIFFERENCE %in% 
  c(0:input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE))
})
```

Also, please notice in your question you mention `>=`, but in your code `<=`.

At last, notice that your axes changes all the time when applying another value for your `DAYS_DIFFERENCE` column, so sometimes the plot seems to change more than it really does when changing the input.

Comment: Based on the comment of @Ronak Shah: that is certainly TRUE as well, I didn't notice that.  With `c(0:input$DAYS_DIFFERENCE)` I converted the column to integer without noticing.

Comment: Yep both of y'alls solutions work. So many ways to skin this cat. Thanks for your help! Take care.